# Mysql 5.5.44 saving 4 bytes characters as "???" on CentOS 6.7 server with utf8mb4 config set

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos6

I have a problem with saving emoji (4 bytes utf-8 in general) characters in mysql database.

My my.cnf file:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
character_set_client = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
character_set_client = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
interactive_timeout=300
key_cache_block_size=4096
max_heap_table_size=32M
max_join_size=1000000000
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
query_cache_size=32M
thread_cache_size=100
tmp_table_size=32M
wait_timeout=7800
max_user_connections=50
myisam_recover_options=FORCE
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_purge_threads=1
innodb_support_xa=0
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid
```

Characters are being saved as "????". However, I've set up mysql database on my local machine and there wasn't any problems with any of non-standard characters, so I guess there is problem with configuration/database version/os version.

Server:
Mysql version 5.5.44
CentOS version 6.7 final
PhpMyAdmin version 4.0.10.7

Local machine:
Mysql version 5.6.26
Windows 8
PhpMyAdmin version 4.4.14

Comment: Could you provide an example SQL query with real data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: "INSERT INTO `858H923`(`sender_id`, `message`, `time_stamp`) VALUES (122, , 1441798040)"  gives me ???????? in message column.

Comment: The message is displaying as emoji in your comment above. What are the actual byte values? Are you sure it's not being saved correctly and just displayed as ???? in your terminal? Try using a programming language to display the byte values which a SELECT statement returns.